# Происхождения слова "приструнить"

Tags: этимология

Раз уж речь зашла об этимологии, у меня тоже вопрос. "Приструнить" — призвать к порядку, укротить. Тут явно прослеживается происхождение от слова "струна", но при чем тут она в данном случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне казалось, что изначально "приструнить" было связано с музыкальными струнными инструментами (может, с балалайкой или гуслями). И "приструнить" - резко зажать струну(-ы) во время игры, чтобы она(они) перестала(-и) звучать. Позже стало применяться к человеку.

Но у Даля (в словарной статье СТРУНА) есть следующее: "...Струнить, вязать струной, или туго, как струной. Струнить волка, лису, поймав живьем, перевязать рыло поперек. Охотники струнят волка своркой, и домой приводят. Когда выношенный беркут волка берет, то старается одной лапой сострунить ему рыло..."

Похоже, это этот вариант предпочтительнее. Как раз значение, пусть и в переносном смысле, сохраняется.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что струна от того что её, во-первых, натягивают, во-вторых настраивают, приводят в порядок. Любая из этих "причин" сама по себе или обе сразу могла реализоваться в "приструнить".
Вроде как "поставить на вытяжку" и "дать указания, как надо себя вести".

Comment: А что ж Вы к гуглу не отсылаете? Там же все есть.

Answer (score 1):

Приструнить - заставить ходить "по струнке", прямо и не сворачивая с пути истинного.

> И. И. Лажечников. Гримаса моего доктора (1813) Капитан строго командовал у себя в доме и хотел, чтобы все в нем ходили в одну ногу и **по струнке, как ходят его солдаты.**

Кроме того, каждая струна имеет свое звучание, вот человека и приходится иногда настраивать на верный тон поведения (дома, на работе, в гостях - везде есть свои тонкости взаимного общения).
Вовремя не перенастроился - получишь по сопатке.

Есть еще выражение : *вытянуться стрункой*, то есть изобразить полную покорность и готовность услужить начальству.
Словарь 1847 :

> **вытянуться в струнку** - стоять прямо, вытянув руки по швам...

В САР 1789-1794 читаем :

> **ПРИСТРУНИВАЮ** ...
> В простонародном употреблении значитъ : принуждаю кого к чему, довожу до невозможности увернуться. *Стоит только приструнить его, а то все скажетъ.*

Возражение.
По поводу слова *струнить* из словаря Даля (пример пользователя [[@Надюшка](/users/308/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)](/users/308/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)). На самом деле существует глагольная форма **со**струнить, то есть **связать** зверя (специальный охотничий термин).

> В. А. Гиляровский. Мои скитания (1927)   Лихой охотник, он принял ловкой хваткой волка за уши, навалился на него, приехал с ним на двор театра, где **сострунил его**, поручил полицейским караулить и, как ни в чем не бывало, звякнул шпорами в зрительном зале и занял свое обычное кресло в первом ряду.

Связь со словом **приструнить** - опосредованная, это просто однокоренные слова. Корень один, приставки и значения слов - РАЗНЫЕ. В словарях и литературе глагол *приструнить* появился намного раньше.

Вопрос преотличный, ставлю большой плюс.